# I have internet connection problem

Tags: internet

I am using ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I am connected to my house WiFi and
The problem is that the only app who have an internet connection is telegram
But the chrome , terminal and vs code have no internet connection
The only app that use the internet is telegram

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Please [edit] your Question and show us the commands `ip link;ip route;service NetworkManager status`. Use proper formatting, so it's readable. Do not use Add comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Without further detailed diagnosis, the cause of the fault cannot be clearly identified. **I suspect** that you have a problem with the network interface settings, specifically you are **missing the DNS server address**.
The consequence is that all applications that use the data entered by name (FQDN) as their communication targets fail to resolve the name to an IP address and the connection cannot be established.
The Telegram application uses directly the IP address to connect to its server (e.g. 149.154.167.91), does not need to resolve names and therefore works.

I don't know if the DNS server address is missing from the network interface because the DHCP server won't assign it to your Ubuntu machine, or because you're setting up the interface manually and forgot about the DNS server.

Please attach the result of a few commands. From this it will then be possible to know more details of the fault.

```
ip a
ip rou
ip neigh
ping -c 3 1.1.1.1
ping -c 3 google.com
dig google.com
```