# Ubuntu 22.04 is connected to internet, but cannot open any website in the browser

Tags: 22.04, internet, dns, dhcp, resolv.conf

HELP!!!

everything was ok until I went to the office and connected my laptop to the Wi-Fi.
then I came home and everything was destroyed!

My Ubuntu is connected to wifi, and the ping of 8.8.8.8 is ok, for example, skype detects wifi is connected but the same Skype can not send any message. chrome and Firefox can not open any website. `apt update` does not work. surprisingly ubuntu's `software` application can install any app!!!

other devices are connected to the same router/wifi and work properly.
ubuntu had worked properly before with the same wifi, but now (after connecting to the office wifi/domain) nothing works

I have tried all the solutions that I found on websites in the last 2 days. nothing solved my problem

please don't talk about `/etc/resolve.conf` or disabling IPv6 or similar solutions. nothing worked!

I am near to removing the whole Ubuntu and returning to Windows again!!!

Comment: tracepath ubuntu.com

Comment: Looks like the office set you up with an http proxy which somehow wasn't unset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong DNS setting on your system. Please, read the answer [I have internet connection problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491046/i-have-internet-connection-problem) and check your setting. Use the commands recommended by answer above and paste here the results.

You are right that the `/etc/resolv.conf` cannot solve problem. This file is ignored by systems which use a netplan or a network manager.

Compare results of these commands:

```
dig google.com
dig google.com @8.8.8.8
```

Which of them translates the name `google.com` (FQDN) to IP address? I suppose the first command response does not include answer section, but second does.
Search for line started by `;; SERVER:` . The DNS server IP address is displayed there.

### Possible Solution

- Use GUI system setting --> Network --> Wireless connection --> Details --> IPv4.
- Switch off automatic DNS setting
- Manually fill the DNS field by address 8.8.8.8
- Save
- Disable and enable again the interface (or reboot your PC)